# Python thread not working as expected when for loop is added

Tags: python, multithreading, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on multithreaded Conway's Game of Life where each cell is a thread. This is my first ever multithreading project.

I have a 10x10 2d array of Cell objects. When I start all of them, "Iteration done" prints 100 times, as expected. But when I add the outer for loop, instead of it printing 300 times, it only prints around 130 times (every time I get a different number). What am I doing wrong? I'm new to multithreading, so excuse me if I made an obvious error.

```
class Cell(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadId, numberOfNeighbors , state):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadId = threadId
        self.numberOfNeighbors = numberOfNeighbors 
        self.state = state 
        self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.iterationNumber= 0
        self.neighbors = None

    def run(self):
        #for x in range(3):
            neighborStates= []
            for neighbor in self.neighbors:
                neighbor.lock.acquire()
                neighbor.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead += 1
                neighborStates.append(neighbor.state)
                neighbor.lock.release()
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                if self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead == self.numberOfNeighbors:
                    self.lock.acquire()
                    self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead = 0
                    self.state = self.calculateState(neighborStates)
                    self.lock.release()
                    break
            print("Iteration done")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that some of your `Cell` objects are getting their `numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` value greater than `numberOfNeighbors` value. That makes them get stuck in the `while` loop and never exit.

Here's how this lockup can happen.

Lets imagine a very simple grid with only two `Cell`s, which I'll call `A` and `B`. They're neighbors to each other, and their `numberOfNeighbors` is 1, since there are no other cells.

`A`'s thread runs first and sets `B.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` to 1. When it gets into the `while` loop, it will sleep, but if it has the chance to wake up, it will keep on looping indefinitely, since its own `numberOfNeighbors` hasn't been incremented yet.

During one of the periods when `A` is sleeping, `B`'s thread takes over, and it will increment `A.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` to 1. When it gets into the `while` loop, it will also sleep, but lets imagine that it wakes up first, since the exact timing of thread scheduling isn't easily predictable. It will then go on to reset its own `numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` and update its own state, since it sees that all of its neighbors have read its value. Then it exits the `while` loop and prints `"Iteration done"`.

In the version of the code without the top-level loop, `B`'s thread is done, and it stops running. A's thread will then catch up, calculating its own new value and printing `"Iteration done"` as well, and then it will exit.

However, with the outer loop uncommented, `B`'s thread can keep on going after printing, and so it will increment `A.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` not to 1, but to 2, since `A` hasn't had a chance to run again since `B`'s thread holds the GIL (the Global Interpreter Lock).

When `A` eventually wakes up later on, the check in the `while` loop won't be correct, because `A.numberOfNeighbors` is 2, not the expected 1. That means `A` will never update its state, and it is stuck in an infinite loop. `B` is also stuck, since `A` won't ever get around to reading its state again, so it will keep waiting forever.

It's also worth noting that `B` is also likely to be copying the wrong state from `A` when it does its second pass, since `A` has not yet updated itself. There's a good chance you'll fix this second issue for free if you prevent the main issue that caused the threads to get stuck in the first place. But thinking about fixing *this* problem might help you understand the problem with the lockup too.

As for how to fix the issue, I think there are a variety of approaches. Which you want will depend on your design. One idea might be to add some sort of global synchronization, which will prevent any `Cell` from running too far ahead of any of its neighbors by making them all wait for all the other cells in the grid to have finished each iteration before the next one can start. Another idea might be to make each `Cell` more aware of the number of updates each of its neighbors has completed, and refuse to read its state before it's on the same iteration as the current `Cell`.

Here's a basic version of that second approach, in which I increment the `iterationNumber` attribute of the `Cell` when I recalculate its state, and in the neighbor scan, I make the code sleep (without holding a lock) if the neighbor it is reading from isn't on the same iteration:

```
class Cell(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadId, numberOfNeighbors , state):  # all this is the same
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadId = threadId
        self.numberOfNeighbors = numberOfNeighbors 
        self.state = state 
        self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.iterationNumber= 0                 # but we're going to use this var below
        self.neighbors = None

    def run(self):
        for x in range(3):                      # restore this loop
            neighborStates= []
            for neighbor in self.neighbors:
                neighbor.lock.acquire()
                while self.iterationNumber != neighbor.iterationNumber: # new stuff here
                    neighbor.lock.release()
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    neighbor.lock.acquire()
                neighbor.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead += 1
                neighborStates.append(neighbor.state)
                neighbor.lock.release()
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                if self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead == self.numberOfNeighbors:
                    self.lock.acquire()
                    self.numberOfNeighborsWhoRead = 0
                    self.state = self.calculateState(neighborStates)
                    self.iterationNumber += 1                            # and here
                    self.lock.release()
                    break
            print("Iteration done")
```

You might be able to streamline some of the synchronization logic by using more advanced synchronization primitives, like a `Semaphore` for the `numberOfNeighborsWhoRead` variable or a `Barrier` to keep all the `Cell`s on the grid working on a single iteration until they're all done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. After reading it I realized that, in this Conway's game of life assignment I'm working on to learn multithreading I'm asked to implement a waiting room using a mutex and two counters - one counting the treads that entered the waiting room, and the other counting the threads that left it. That waiting room would have solved this iteration issue, but I thought that the code I already had was incorrect. Now that I know that, I will try to implement the waiting room.